# How to put the jsp compiler in the jdk?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, compiler-construction, java

We compile the jsp page with the help of web logic jsp compiler, or tomcat jsp compiler. Is this possible to compile the jsp with the help of jdk or jre ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope not you can compile the jsps using JDK or JRE. The compiler on your web server does that.

Comment: then why this jsp compiler is not placed in the jdk ? Whats the reason behind it ? All we knows the java is so powerfull language. Its not a big deal for java teams to develop a jsp compiler in the jdk. But still we use web server to compile jsp page.

Comment: Java is designed to be used in conjunction with many other technologies. JSP is one of them. It won't be appropriated to include the functionality of all such technologies in Java. As an example, for those who are working on Java alone, JSP features won't be of any use. It is the best approach to divide the functionality and working on modules rather than working on the whole thing.